# Reissuing recaptcha api keys to an existing domain

Tags: recaptcha

Our APIkeys were issued several years ago and since then the person who set them up has moved on. We have no idea what login/password was used (although I'm not sure that matters much now)

If I request new API keys for our domain will this break the existing recaptcha interactions until I correct the code?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You will only need to replace the captcha keys from your code and nothing will change for the user, so no replacing the keys won't break your application

Comment: What I probably meant to say was if I get the keys re-issued will that break the interaction UNTIL I replace the keys in the code? That 10-15 minute gap of requesting keys and updating the code on our website host?

Comment: You can keep the old keys until the new ones replace them this way there won't be any issue with it